# Alfred - Open selected url in browser

Tags: alfred

I'm looking for a way to open the url in clipboard with Alfred - using shortcut key. Can we do this ?

Example:

I select an url then I click a combo key. My browser will open that url

Comment: I don't understand. Is Alfred involved in this? You select url in random program. You press a key. The browser opens the URL. How does this involve Alfred?

Comment: actually, alfred can search google of selected text. So it can do this thing :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've resolved the problem myself. Here is the guide :

In Alfred ( make sure you have Powerpack ), make a shellscript in extensions:

```
/usr/bin/open -a "/Applications/Google Chrome.app" {query}
```

Create an extensions in hotkeys which use our created extension with the argument is selected text in OS X.

Set your keyboard shortcut. And now, when you want to open selected url, just select the url then press your keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

Easy.

1. Bring up the Alfred window
2. Press <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>
3. Press <kbd>enter</kbd>

Comment: just edit my question :)

I want to open using a shortcut key or even better, just select text and open. No need to cmd+v